# Overwriting a file in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file, of which a part is shown below:

```
OUTPUT_FILENAME="out.Received.Power.x.0.y.1.z.0.41
X_TX=0
Y_TX=1
Z_TX=0.41
```

I would like to automatically change some part of it with BASH: every time i see OUTPUT_FILENAME i want to over write the name next to it and change it with a new one. Then i want to do the same with the values X_TX, Y_TX and Z_TX: delete the value next to it and rewrite a new one. For example instead of X_TX=0 i want X_TX=0.3 or viceversa.
Do you think it's possible?Maybe with grep or so..

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this:

i.e. to replace X_TX= with X_TX=123 you can do:

```
sed -i -e 's/X_TX=.*/X_TX=123/g' /tmp/file1.txt
```

Comment: yes exactly i just found out!the problem is that the value that i want to change it changes iteratively in a while so i will have to do something like `sed -i -e 's/T_XT=.*/X_TX="$X"/g' file.dat` but it doesnt work it just writes $X but i want the value in X not just $X!!

Comment: it's the quotes - use "" for outside quotes and '' for inside ones: sed -i -e "s/T_XT=.*/X_TX='$X'/g" file.dat

Answer (score 0):

One option using `awk`. Your values are passed as variables to the `awk` script and substituted when exists a match:

```
awk -v outfile="str_outfile" -v x_tx="str_x" -v y_tx="str_y" -v z_tx="str_z" '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "=" }
    $1 == "OUTPUT_FILENAME" { $2 = outfile; print; next }
    $1 == "X_TX" { $2 = x_tx; print $0; next }
    $1 == "Y_TX" { $2 = y_tx; print $0; next }
    $1 == "Z_TX" { $2 = z_tx; print $0; next }
' infile
```